# UICollectionView проблема выделения

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

имеем на странице два UICollectionView например

```
var selectedIndex = Int ()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    if(collectionView == self.collectionView) {

        cell.name_category.text = heroes[indexPath.row].category_name

        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
        else
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }

    }

    if(collectionView == self.collectionViewData) {
            cell.name_news.text = heroes[indexPath.row].name
            cell.text_news.text = heroes[indexPath.row].desc


    }


    return cell;

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   // return print(indexPath.row)
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row

   // self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

но не могу решить проблему с выделением ячейки в конкретной коллекции. Если выделить одну ячейку в одной коллекции то она будет и на другой отражатся

Answer (score 0):

У Вас с каждой UICollectionView работа должна быть отдельно. Сейчас же один индекс строки для обеих.
Рассмотрите пример, набросал для наглядности один из вариантов. Каждой UICollectionView присваиваем тег по которому различаем с какой из них взаимодействуем:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView1: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView2: UICollectionView!

    var collectionViewTestModel1: [Bool] = [true, false, false, false]
    var collectionViewTestModel2: [Bool] = [true, false, false, false, false]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView1.tag = 0
        collectionView2.tag = 1 // Присваиваем тег чтобы различать

        collectionView1.delegate = self
        collectionView2.delegate = self

        collectionView1.dataSource = self
        collectionView2.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Обрабатываем выделение и делаем reload этой cell
        if collectionView.tag == 0 {
            collectionViewTestModel1[indexPath.row] = !collectionViewTestModel1[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            collectionViewTestModel2[indexPath.row] = !collectionViewTestModel2[indexPath.row]
        }
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellTest", for: indexPath)

        // Определяем ячейка выделена или нет и устанавливаем цвет
        var isCellSelected: Bool
        if collectionView.tag == 0 {
            isCellSelected = collectionViewTestModel1[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            isCellSelected = collectionViewTestModel2[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = isCellSelected ? .green : .orange

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Отдаем количество ячеек в каждой из UICollectionView
        if collectionView.tag == 0 {
            return collectionViewTestModel1.count
        } else {
            return collectionViewTestModel2.count
        }
    }
}
```